# Can't get cookies which makes me unauthrorized even if logged in express/mysql jwt

Tags: mysql, express, jwt

```
export const deletePost = (req, res) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json("Not authenticated!");

  jwt.verify(token, "jwtkey", (err, userInfo) => {
    if (err) return res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!");

    const postId = req.params.id;
    const q = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE `id` = ? AND `uid` = ?";

    db.query(q, [postId, userInfo.id], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return res.status(403).json("You can delete only your post!");

      return res.json("Post has been deleted!");
    });
  });
```

};
The code above is my controller for  delete function

```
export const login = (req, res) => {
  //CHECK USER

  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length === 0) return res.status(404).json("User not found!");

    //Check password
    const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(
      req.body.password,
      data[0].password
    );

    if (!isPasswordCorrect)
      return res.status(400).json("Wrong username or password!");

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: data[0].id }, "jwtkey");
    const { password, ...other } = data[0];
    console.log(token)
    res
      .cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(other);
  });
};
```

The code above is used for login

My problem is that when i logged in the cookie seems to set correctly since when i console log the token from the login function the token is being printed however when i print the token using the deletepost function it returns undefined

```
export const logout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("token", {
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true
  }).status(200).json("User has been logged out.")
};
```

in addition the code above doesn't clear the cookie from the browser, all help will be appreciated thanks

```
import express from "express";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
import usersRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import cors from "cors";

import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5173", // Replace this with the URL of your frontend
    credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies) to be sent by the frontend
  })
);

app.use(express.json());


app.use("/api/posts", postRoutes);
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", usersRoutes);

app.listen(5175, () => {
  console.log("Connected to Backend");
});
```

Comment: You probably forgot to use [cookie-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html) middleware.

Comment: I used cookie parser in my backend

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem, your code works fine for me, maybe you can make sure you are using the cookie-parser middleware before all other endpoints.

Comment: Hello updated my post to show cookieparser i still get undefined and logout is still now functional idk why